# Why do I need to bind to a dependency property in code behind but not in view model?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm writing a user control. Xaml & code behind. In order to bind to a property in the code behind the property needs to be a dependency property. Understood.

Why then can I bind to a poco which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` in a view model which is set as the view's data context but not in the code behind?

xaml:

```
XAxis="{Binding ElementName=TimeSeriesChartControl, Path=XAxis}"
```

Code behind:

```
public IAxis XAxis
{
    get { return (IAxis)GetValue(XAxisProperty); }
    set { SetValue(XAxisProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty XAxisProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("XAxis", typeof(IAxis), typeof(TimeSeriesChart), new PropertyMetadata(default(IAxis)));
```

This property has to be a dependency property. If I was to implement a clr property here, the binding would fail.

Why can I implement a clr property in a view model class but not in the code behind?

Comment: Could you also include a example of how you would do it with a clr property that is failing, and when it does fail what is the specific error message/incorrect behavior you are getting?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because dependency properties support binding to both other dependency properties or to things that implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

A view model should try to stay platform agnostic and not know anything about the view, by using dependency properties in the view model you tie it to be WPF supported only and you are "leaking" information about the view back to the view model..

Comment: Ok thanks, so why can I not bind a property in my user control xaml to a clr property in the code behind?

Comment: You can, so long as that property is a properly declared dependency property or you do the INotifyPropertyChanged pattern on that property. However doing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` pattern on anything that derives from [`DependencyObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject(v=vs.110).aspx) is frowned upon.

Comment: @Hardgraf if you are still having problems, update your question with a edit showing a example that is not working.

Comment: Ah, ok so if I implement INPC & raise propertyChanged event on a clr property in code behind then the binding will work. However, it is bad practice to implement the interface on the user control because it inherits from DependencyObject. Therefore to enable property changed notification we bind to a dependency property...